# MediaPicker-based iOS app Not Playing All Songs

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, mpmediapickercontroller

I've been looking at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios) for information on how to locate songs in a user's music library on their iPhone. Everything is working as it's supposed to, except that songs that are purchased but not on the user's phone do not play.

Does anyone know a way to fix this, or know how to test to see if the song is purchased vs installed and then alert the user?

Below is the code I'm using from the tutorial that selects and plays the songs:

```
/*
 * This method is called when the user presses button. It displays a media picker
 * screen to the user configured to show only audio files.
 */
- (IBAction)pickSong:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems: NO];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}


#pragma mark - Media Picker Delegate

/*
 * This method is called when the user chooses something from the media picker screen. It dismisses the media picker screen
 * and plays the selected song.
 */
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {

    // remove the media picker screen
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    // grab the first selection (media picker is capable of returning more than one selected item,
    // but this app only deals with one song at a time)
    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];

    // display title of song in a navigation bar
    //NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    //[_navBar.topItem setTitle:title];

    // get a URL reference to the selected item
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    // pass the URL to playURL:, defined earlier in this file
    [self playURL:url];
}
```

Comment: Do you solved it somehow? I have exactly same question.

Comment: I haven't yet @PetrBrázdil....and I can't seem to find anything on here or elsewhere on how to address the issue. Glad I'm not the only one with the problem though!

Comment: Hey @PetrBrázdil, have you figured out how to do this yet? I haven't gotten anywhere :/